# How to automate notifications using power automate when a new field is created in DB

Tags: azure-logic-apps, powerapps

So am working with a team of business intelligence analysts and they are to create a workflow for a certain task, my job now is to create a check notification for them, for instance in a field called `PhoneNumber` if the number of characters is supposed to be 11 and the user inputs 12, it should send a notification that wrong data set have been inputted

so my question is, which will do the work power automate or logic apps?
Anyone that can shed light on this, please do, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can also do this using Azure Logic Apps.***

***-  Fisrtly, you need to create an azure function or web app where you will check the condition of your phone number field.***

***- Then send the output of function or web app as Triggering  http request or use can use Azure Service Bus Trigger to do so.***

***- Then you can use Azure Logic App to send notification to Outlook , Gmail, etc***

***Through Gmail:***

[image]

***Through Outlook:***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit generic question.
What is the user input UI? Is it a powerppas/crm/any background program or so on.

If you want to run your logic directly on database (i.e on create/updated) and on Phone Number specific field, you can do so.

I would go with power automate. There are different ways you can send notification in power automate.

1. Power automate notifaction action
2. Power automate Email action
3. Outlook Email
4. If you use Power Apps, you can catch error in powerapps itself and send app notificaiton

Comment: thank you brother, but the error is not coming from Azure, because they write on azure sql

Comment: "it a powerppas/crm/any background program" haven't gotten clarification on this yet....its a new project and I just want to know my stance on it....still learning and asking more